# why compilation error

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
const int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
int b[a[2]];
int main(){return 0;}
```

Why the compilation error is coming with this code. Could someone explain in brief, concise and exact behavior.

Comment: Please include the error you are getting in your question.

Comment: also why you want to do something this convoluted.

Answer (score 2):

I am getting with gcc 4.6

```
tt.cc:5:11: error: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token
```

I find the error message quite explanatory. You cannot declare

```
int b[a[2]];
```

you should use

```
int b[3];
```

And you very probably want to use `std::vector` instead.

#### C++11 tricks

you could compile your code with a C++11 compiler (like just released GCC 4.7) by declaring

```
constexpr  int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
```

but that seems insane to me. You really want to use vectors or some other container type.

Comment: It is not a compile-time constant. A compile-time constant is known at compilation time.

Comment: Than why does the following work? `const int x = 2;int c[x];`

Comment: Roughly speaking, array dimensions should be "easily" constant to the compiler (ie `const` definition, or *simple* arithmetic expressions on them). If you want details, dive into the C++03 standard (many hundreds pages to read). Or use C++11 with `constexpr`. Always ask yourself: how would I implement the compiler to do such tricks? If you don't really know, don't expect it from the compiler! And trust the compiler's error messages...

Answer (score 1):

#### For C++03:

**8.3.4.1** An array declaration is:

```
D1[constant-expression]
```

`constant-expression` is, in this case, an integral constant expression.

If we look at **5.19.1** we find what an integral constant expression is:

- literals
- `const` variables
- static data members of integral or enumeration types initialized with constant expressions
- non-type template parameters of integral or enumeration types
- `sizeof` expressions
- floating literals, if cast to integral or enumeration types

In particular, except for `sizeof`, the following can not be used:

- functions
- class objects
- pointers or references
- assignment, increment, decrement, function-call or comma operators

In your case, `a[2]` is neither, so it can't be used as the array's length.

#### For C++11:

Roughly the same, only that you can declare `a` as a `constexpr` and use it as the array's length. However, this coding style is generally bad, and you shouldn't write stuff like that unless you've evaluated all other options.

### EDIT:

I don't see why the question was downvoted. I find it very interesting:

1) You can actually do this in C++11, with `constexpr`

2) Even in C++03, the behavior is at least strange (if you don't search the standard):

```
const int x = 2;
const int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
int c[x];    //compiles
int b[a[2]]; //doesn't
```

Comment: The question was down-voted because the original poster did not bother to give the compiler's error message he was getting.

Answer (score 0):

> int b[a[2]];

You need to to provide a compile-time available array size (that is, a fixed size array), or allocate dynamically using `malloc` etc.

Comment: "compile-time available array size" What does that mean?

Comment: Compiler needs size for `b`. It should be constant. Code snippet suggests it is a variable instead.

Comment: `**const** int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};` it's constant.

Comment: Compiler does not have to be that smart, it has a variable reference there and it fires the error. If it was just a const variable instead `int b[c]`, compiler might be smart enough to figure that out though.

Comment: It's not about whether the compiler is smart or not. It's about what the standard dictates. Compilers aren't standard compliant. Just because the code doesn't compile on one compiler, doesn't mean it's illegal.

Comment: It is not about what you say. It is a bad-defined question, without reference to platform, compiler version, to error message, to error line reference. And the question is "Why the compilation error is coming with this code. Could someone explain in brief" So the answer is given.

Comment: I agree with that (which is why I didn't downvote). But I found that the question was not fully answered. I mean, there's much more info that can be given than just saying "it's illegal", even with no reference provided.